# How do you get rid of deleted sub-interfaces from NVRAM?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios-12

This is more of a cosmetic issue however it does bug me....

I removed the sub-interfaces off a 3845 router by issuing.

```
no int fast1/0.10
no int fast1/0.15
default int fast1/0
```

When I do a `show run`....the subinterfaces are no longer there. However, a `show ip int br` has them listed as follows:

```
router#sh ip int br
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
FastEthernet1/0            unassigned      YES manual down                  down 
FastEthernet1/0.13         unassigned      YES NVRAM  deleted               down
FastEthernet1/0.30         unassigned      YES NVRAM  deleted               down
```

How do I remove them from NVRAM without a reboot?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`reload` is the only way to purge them.